Toilet leaking to inside the bowl. Replace flap, valve, entire toilet?
My toilet has been making dripping sounds and in the past couple of days it evolved to water streaming sounds.
I can see water going down the bowl walls, and it's staining the bowl.
I replaced the flap a couple of months ago, and when I press on the flap with my hands the water sounds and flow in the bowl stops.
I don't believe the flap is the problem (since it's relatively new), but rather the o-ring or something.
I can see the ring where the flap sits is not in the best of shapes, it should be more than 10 years old.
Should I look for a new flap, or should I change the entire valve thing (I don't know how it's called). Or should I just replace the entire toilet?





Could the chain be a little taut and sometimes pulling up the flapper?   Could the float or float arm be interfering with the chain sometimes?  Could the styrofoam tank limer be interfering with the front of the flapper sometimes?  Could the rust stain on the lip of the flush hole be contributing to the leak?

The flapper port looks almost pristine to me. Are you sure your new flapper was compatible? Was it a soft one of high quality? This shouldn't be complicated.

See the dark brown stain.
That is fixable.
Clean it up, probably try vinegar since it might be just caulk.
If you decide to replace the whole assembly be aware you will be breaking another seal (to the tank) and have to take care of that. It is still a DYI job.
No need to buy new toilet.

This is what I think the problem is coming from. Could that be rust? Because I'm seeing brown lines in the toilet bowl.

@GrizzlyFoxCat yes it could be rust

Caulk? How would caulk get in there, and what's vinegar going to tod?

You can try to clean the seat the flapper sits on to seal the water. If that doesn't work,you can try a a flush valve repair kit .
Another way to fix is to remove the tank. There is a big nut that holds the flush valve assembly to the bottom of the tank. If that is not tight it could allow water to flow into the bowl. However it usually also shows as a leak under the tank. You will need a flush valve seal. However disturbing other parts that are old can result in more issues.
There may be leakage from the fill valve and the flush valve is ok.
Given the age of the toilet, the prudent thing to do is either get a toilet rebuild kit and change all the parts in the tank and the tank seals.
OR
Purchase a new toilet.

Thanks. How would a leakage from the fill valve result in water running down in the bowl?

@GrizzlyFoxCat fill vale is where the water goes in the bowl when the flap valve is open
